# Show that $A$ is an ideal of $R$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring. Suppose $\emptyset\neq A\subseteq R$ and $$a,b\in A\implies a+b\in A,$$
$$r\in R\  \text{and}\  a\in A\implies ar,ra\in A .$$

Further suppose for each $a\in A,$ there exists an integer $n\neq 0$ such that $na\in aR+Ra$. It is required to prove that $A$ is an ideal of $R$. I believe all that is needed to be proved is that $$a,b\in A\implies a-b\in A.$$

However I cannot understand how to proceed after the following point.

Assume $a,b\in A$. Then there exists $m\neq 0$ such that $ma=ar_1+r_2a$ and $n\neq 0$ such that $nb=bs_1+s_2b$, where $r_1,r_2,s_1,s_2\in R$.

Please give me a hint. Thanks.

Added later: $R$ can be embedded in a ring with identity as follows. Consider $R\times\mathbb{Z}$ with addition defined as $(r,m)+(s,n)=(r+s,m+n)$ and multiplication defined as $(r,m)(s,n)=(rs+nr+ms, mn)$. Then $R\times \mathbb{Z}$ is a ring with identity namely $(0,1)$. Furthermore we have $R\cong R\times\{0\}$ with $R\times\{0\}$ a subring of $R\times \mathbb{Z}$. So $R$ is embedded in a ring with identity.

Now let's take $a,b\in A$. Consider $(a,0),(b,0)\in A\times \{0\}$. Then $(a-b,0)=(a,0)+(0,-1)(b,0)\in A\times \{0\}$. So $a-b\in A$. Therefore $A$ is an ideal.

Is this argument alright?

Why is the stipulation "for each $a\in A,$ there exists an integer $n\neq 0$ such that $na\in aR+Ra$" given?

Comment: $a,b\in A$. Then $-b=(-1)b\in A$ and so $a+(-b)\in A$.

Comment: How do you know that $-b\in A$?

Comment: $r=-1$ and $b\in A$ implies $-b=rb\in A$

Comment: The assumption $1\in R$ is not given.

Comment: If not, you can extend each ring to have a unit element.

Comment: @Wuestenfux That wouldn't change $A$.

Comment: could you please check the "added later" part?

Comment: About the "added later" is the theorem 1.10 chapter III in algebra book of Thomas hungerford.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The condition $0\in A$ is ensured by $A\ne\emptyset$ and $0a\in A$. So what you need to prove is that $-a\in A$, whenever $a\in A$.

Let's choose $n\ne0$ with $na=ar+sa$. Then 
$$
(-n)a=-na=-ar-sa=a(-r)+(-s)a\in aR+Ra,$$
so it's not restrictive to assume $n>0$.

By the first property, $(n-1)a\in A$ (this is the integer $1$); moreover $(-n)a\in aR+Ra$, so $(-n)a\in A$, by the second property, so
$$
-a=(n-1)a+(-n)a\in A
$$

---

The “added part” in the question glosses over the fact that you'd need to prove that $(0,-1)(b,0)\in A\times\{0\}$, which is the same as proving that $-b\in A$.